# daterange on a django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I use Django, the Django REST Framework plus django-filters (alex/django-filter).

I have a model with the fields start_date and end_date and I'm trying to build a date api-endpoint which should receive a date and respond with items where (start_date < date) and (end_date > date).
There is a [DateRangeFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#daterangefilter) but I can't figure out how to use it. Here is my code so far:

urls.py:

```
url(r'^api/sales/$', views.SaleItemList.as_view(), name='sales'),
```

views.py:

```
class SaleItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    city = django_filters.CharFilter(name='trade_item__vendor__city')
    title = django_filters.CharFilter(name='trade_item__title')
    date = django_filters.DateRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = SaleItem
        fields = ['sale_price', 'sale_date_start', 'sale_date_end', 'trade_item']

class SaleItemList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = SaleItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SaleItemListSerializer
    filter_class = SaleItemFilter
```

serializers.py:

```
class SaleItemListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SaleItem
        fields = ("sale_price", "sale_date_start", "sale_date_end", "trade_item", "slogan")
```

I can filter for exact dates so far:

/api/sales/?sale_date_start=2015-05-22

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I can't speak to the Django REST Framework part of your question, but I hope I can lend some insight to the django-filter part!

If you use a DateRangeFilter, the result would be a dropdown with the options "any date", "today", "past 7 days", "this month" and "this year".

If your variable is 'date', either of these will give you a date range with the label "Date Range":

```
date_range = DateRangeFilter(field_name='date')
date = DateRangeFilter(label='Date_Range')
```

The difference is that if you use the first one, you can use your variable "date" again, so you could give your user the choice to filter by start date, end date, or both (to get dates between), all using the same date variable.

(You can only use "date" to the left of the equal sign one time (or not at all)).

To get the start and end date, do:

```
start_date = DateFilter(field_name='date',lookup_expr=('lt'),) 
end_date = DateFilter(field_name='date',lookup_expr=('gt'))
```

You don't need to call "date" again in Meta, but you can.  You do need to call something.  It could be your date, or some other field you want to filter.

Here is a full code and screenshot example:

```
from django_filters import DateRangeFilter,DateFilter
from wesapp.models import MyModel

class SaleItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(name='date',lookup_type=('gt'),) 
    end_date = DateFilter(name='date',lookup_type=('lt'))
    date_range = DateRangeFilter(name='date')

    class Meta:
        model = SaleItem
        fields = ['entered_by',]
```

[image]

Comment: fyi: `lookup_type` appears to have changed to `lookup_expr` in later versions

Comment: also `field_name` instead of `name`

Answer (score 11):

I know this is old post but to give additional answer you can enable from and to datepicker also by the following method. Datepicker using django_filters.

```
import django_filters
from django_filters.widgets import RangeWidget

Date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

Comment: I was looking exactly for that. Simple and easy.

Comment: I did same but I am getting ```'DateFromToRangeFilter' object has no attribute 'split'``` error. Can you help me please. When I tried other Filterset method I got same error.

Answer (score 7):

just an edit for the current django version replace `name` with `field_name`, replace `lookup_type` with `lookup_expr` :

An example is given below for filters.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django_filters

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):       
    username = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    first_name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    last_name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    year_joined = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date_joined', lookup_expr='year',label='Year Joined')
    year_joined__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date_joined', lookup_expr='year__gt',label='Year Joined Greater Than')
    year_joined__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date_joined', lookup_expr='year__lt',label='Year Joined Less Than')
    date_range = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(field_name='date_joined')
    start_date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='date_joined',lookup_expr='lt',label='Date joined is before (mm/dd/yyyy):')
    end_date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='date_joined',lookup_expr='gt',label='Date joined is after (mm/dd/yyyy):')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', ]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also try the `DateFromToRangeFilter`
This would enable you to do this:

```
f = F({'date_0': '2016-01-01', 'date_1': '2016-02-01'})
```

Where F is a `FilterSet` class with `date = DateFromToRangeFilter`

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/widgets.html#rangewidget

Comment: How do you get two boxes to show up for each date instead of 1?